# neovim: autocompletion on user defined command plugin

Tags: autocompletion, neovim, plugin-system, vimscript-python

I am write a plugin for neovim in python using [this client](https://github.com/neovim/python-client) and I looking for a way to offer completion when executing a command. I have look at the [following example](https://neovim.io/doc/user/remote_plugin.html) to structure my plugin. As an example, I could have a command Foo and when you call it the first time:

```
Foo bar
```

the second time you could autocomplete:

```
Foo b<tab> -> Foo bar
```

as an example my this is what my plugin look like in my ~/.config/nvim/rplugin/python3/my_plugin.py:

```
import neovim

@neovim.plugin
class MyPlugin(object):
    def __init__(self, vim):
        self.vim = vim
        self.current_args = []

    @neovim.command("Cmd", range="", nargs="*", sync=True)
    def CmdHandler(self, args, range):
        if args[0] not in self.current_args:
            self.current_args.append(args[0])
```

And I guess I would need to write a function for the completion for
the command?

```
@neovim.function("MyCompletionFunction")
def MyCompletionFunction(self, args):
    ...
```

and set my function as completion function for my command.
any help appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, when you define a new command in the way I do, a [user-command](https://neovim.io/doc/user/map.html#user-commands), you can specify in which way the command  will be autocompleted ([command-completion](https://neovim.io/doc/user/map.html#:command-completion)) and there's a lot of choices.
So the way I did it is with a customlist function as follow:

```
@neovim.plugin
class MyPlugin(object):

    def __init__(self, vim):
        self.vim = vim
        self.values = []

    @neovim.command("Cmd", complete='customlist,MyFunc', range="", nargs="1", sync=True)
    def Cmd(self, args, range):
        new_value = args[0]
        self.values.append(new_value)

    @neovim.function("MyFunc", sync=True)
    def MyFunc(self, *args, **kwargs):
        return self.values
```

so each time I exec the command

```
:Cmd value1
```

next time, I can

```
:Cmd va<Tab>  -> :Cmd value1
```